# 'setInternet2' is not an exported object from 'namespace-utils' in R

Tags: r

While installing package 'ff'

> install.packages("ff")

Error: 'setInternet2' is not an exported object from 'namespace:utils'

Execution halted

Warning messages:

1: In install.packages("ff")

installation of package 'ff' had non-zero exit status

Comment: The package is riddled with errors http://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_ff.html but `setInternet2` is indeed exported by the utils package so I'm not sure why the error.  I can not replicate on a Windows 7 machine running R 3.0.3 (I install with success).  Maybe post `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Possibly you are not on a windows platform?